# How to implement the interface properties in child class?

Tags: c#

First i entered 2 values for the base class do the calculation. Then I entered 2 values in the chill class but the variable Num1 and Num2 both are 0. Why? and base class doesn't.

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Calculation addition = new Calculation();
            addition.AskValue();
            addition.Calc();
            Sub subtraction = new Sub();
            subtraction.AskValue();
            subtraction.Calc();
        }
    }
```

Interface with 2 properties

```
    internal interface IInter
    {
        public int Num1
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public int Num2
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
```

Base class with interface. the base class properies Num1 and Num2 work fine.

```
    class Calculation : IInter
    {
        private int _num1, _num2;

        public int Num1 
        { get => _num1; 
          set => _num1 = value; 
        }
        public int Num2 
        { get => _num2; 
          set => _num2 = value; 
        }

        //functie addition 
        virtual public void Calc()
        {
            int result= Num1 + Num2;
            Console.WriteLine("{0} + {1} = {2}", Num1, Num2, result);
        }

        //functie ask value
        public void AskValue()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter 1e value for calcucation.");
            Num1 =Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter 2e value for calcucation.");
            Num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }

    }
```

child class with interface. Properthies Num1 and Num2 are always 0.

```
    class Sub:Calculation , IInter
    {
        private int _num1, _num2;

        public int Num1
        {
            get => _num1;
            set => _num1 = value;
        }
        public  int Num2
        {
            get => _num2;
            set => _num2 = value;
        }
        //override base class calc function subtract instead of add
        override public void Calc()
        {
            int result = Num1 - Num2;
            Console.WriteLine("{0} + {1} = {2}", Num1, Num2, result);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your `Sub` class is shadowing its parent `Calculation` properties. You get a compilation WARNING that says that.

Comment: Hi Emanual, Yes indeed. in the child class have 2 warnings. i tried  to use new keyword but still the same.
Warning CS0108 'Sub.Num1' hides inherited member 'Calculation.Num1'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.

Comment: It says 'Use the new keyword if hiding *was intended*'. In your case you did not intend it. You should mark the properties as 'virtual' in the parent class and 'override' in the child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Parent class you can mark them as **virtual**

```
class Calculation : IInter
{
    public virtual int Num1
```

Then in your Child class you can use the override keyword:

```
class Sub:Calculation , IInter
{
    public override int Num1
```

Try reading this;

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/inheritance

And specifically, this page;

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/knowing-when-to-use-override-and-new-keywords